# Traducción de la pestaña "Saves" (previamente conocida como "Marcadores" o "Favoritas" ("Bookmarks"))

Tags: discusión, traducciones

[Como se ha reportado en Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019), la pestaña *Bookmarks* (lo que para nosotros sería *Favoritas* o *Marcadores*) pasó a llamarse *Saves*. Esto deriva en ciertos inconvenientes en la traducción de las siguientes cadenas:

- [*All saves*](https://es.traducir.win/strings/19022)
- [*For later*](https://es.traducir.win/strings/19125)
- [*Saves for $DisplayName$*](https://es.traducir.win/strings/19213) (el título de la pestaña en el navegador)
- [*Unsave*](https://es.traducir.win/strings/19180)

Si tradujéramos *Saves* como *Guardados*, ¿cómo podríamos traducir tales cadenas?:

- ***All saves***: ¿*Todos los guardados*?
- ***For later***: ¿*Para más tarde*? ¿*Para después*? ¿*Para luego*?
- ***Saves for $DisplayName$***: ¿*Guardados de $DisplayName$*?
- ***Unsave***: ¿*Dejar de guardar*? (me parece que "desguardar" no es opción...)

La idea es llegar a un consenso. ¿Qué (otras) traducciones sugieren?

Comment: El  problema es que "guardado" hace referencia a un tiempo verbal que no es precisamente "saves" sino "saved"

Comment: @MauricioContreras Exactamente, por eso mencionaba que eso trae problemas en la traducción (de hecho en inglés [también dieron otras sugerencias](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves#comment1274165_382019) como para que no se llame "Saves"). [Otros son más radicales](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves#comment1274167_382019) (?

Comment: Es correcto usar Guardado como nombre / sustantivo --> De https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivaci%C3%B3n
***Sustantivación de verbos** 
La acción prototípica asociada a un verbo se obtiene mediante sufijos derivativos deverbativos como -miento, -ción, -ada/-ado, -ida/-ido etc: aburrir > aburrimiento, describir > descripción, llegar > llegada, partir > partida.*

Answer (score 8):

Me parece que debemos tener presente cómo se mostrarían estas etiquetas en la interfaz de usuario:

[image]

1. "Saves" -> "Guardados"
2. "All Saves" -> "Todos"
   No es necesario "Todos los guardados" o algo equivalente y similarmente largo porque "Guardados" estaría a la vista
3. "n saved items" -> "n elementos guardados" o "n publicaciones guardadas"
4. "For later" -> "Para después"
5. "My Lists" -> "Mis listas"

Comment: No comparto la traducción de "All Saves" por simplemente "Todos" porque desconocemos donde más puede estar referenciado (no tiene porque aparecer solo en esa ventana, quizás en alguna ayuda o desde otro lugar también apuntarán allí).  Aunque quede horrorosamente largo, yo voto por "Todos los Guardados" (y lo pongo en mayúscula para que se entienda mejor que estamos hablando del concepto de "Guardados").